# Ng-hide not working in data list Angular

Tags: angularjs, datalist, ng-hide

```
<body ng-app>
<datalist id="dataList">
  <select id="select">  
    <option ng-repeat="val in temp" ng-hide="true"  >{{val}}</option>
  </select>
</datalist>                            
<input  list="dataList"   ng-model="fromLocation"  />
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/awnqm/284/
This is the fiddle, i have a simple datalist and an input (using that datalist).
Why the ng-hide in options tag is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ngHide does not work for options. You need to use ngIf. But, it's available from Angular 1.1.5 ([Angular 1.1.5 introduced the ngIf directive](https://recalll.co/app/?q=UPDATE%3A%20Angular%201.1.5%20introduced%20the%20ngIf%20directive)). So, update your Angular version and use ngIf to resolve the issue. See

```
<body ng-app>
<datalist id="dataList">
  <select id="select">  
    <option ng-repeat="val in temp" ng-if="false"  >{{val}}</option>
  </select>
</datalist>                            
<input  list="dataList"   ng-model="fromLocation"  />
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gosha_Fighten/awnqm/288/

ngHide simply applied `display: none` CSS to an element which does not work for options. For example, [[IE11, Win7] "display: none" on OPTION tag is ignored](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/848449/ie11-win7-display-none-on-option-tag-is-ignored). ngIf does not render an element at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I had some idea about ng-f but was not aware about the version issue. Thanks

Comment: JFYI, I've updated my answer to provide more info on how it works.